# how to create columns in angular material card?

Tags: css, angular, flexbox, angular-material

How do we divide an angular mat card grid in parts ? Anyone has an idea here ?. I wanted to create a division same with the image below , I have provided my sample code below with the mat card and inputs.Thank you.

Already tried lot of stuff but cant seem to figure it out.

[This is the division that I want][1]

Code

```
<div><hr style="width:38%;margin-top:50px;background-color:#E5E5E5;"></div>
        <mat-card class="custom">
            <mat-card-content>
                <div fxLayout="row" fxFlex="100" fxLayoutAlign="space-around center">
                    <div fxFlex="45%">
                        <mat-form-field class="full-width" appearance="fill" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                            <mat-label>Firstname</mat-label>
                            <input matInput>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </div>
                    <div fxFlex="45%">
                        <mat-form-field class="full-width" appearance="fill" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                            <mat-label>Lastname</mat-label>
                            <input matInput>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </mat-card-content>
            <mat-card-content>
                <div fxLayout="row" fxFlex="100">
                    <div fxFlex="45%">
                        <mat-form-field class="full-width" appearance="fill" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                            <mat-label>Firstname</mat-label>
                            <input matInput>
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </mat-card-content>
        </mat-card>
```

Comment: can you provide a stackblitz please?

Comment: you should have an unique mat-card-content, inside the content create a div fxLayout="column" and inside this the two fex-layout="row" fxFlex=100. NOTE: I never used fxLayout so only imagine how this can work

Comment: @AakashGarg , I dont know how to create stackblitz and adding components to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a tentative, not sure if it's exactly what you want:

```
<mat-card class="custom" style="width: 500px">
    <mat-card-content>
        <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between">
            <div fxLayout="column" fxFlex="0 0 47%">
                <mat-form-field class="full-width" appearance="fill" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                    <mat-label>Firstname</mat-label>
                    <input matInput>
                </mat-form-field>
            </div>
            <div fxLayout="column" fxFlex="0 0 47%">
                <mat-form-field class="full-width" appearance="fill" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                    <mat-label>Lastname</mat-label>
                    <input matInput>
                </mat-form-field>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start">
            <div fxLayout="column" fxFlex="0 0 47%">
                <mat-form-field class="full-width" appearance="fill" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                    <mat-label>Phone Number</mat-label>
                    <input matInput>
                </mat-form-field>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between">
            <div fxLayout="column" fxFlex="0 0 47%">
                <mat-form-field class="full-width" appearance="fill" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                    <mat-label>Company Name</mat-label>
                    <input matInput>
                </mat-form-field>
            </div>
            <div fxLayout="column" fxFlex="0 0 47%">
                <mat-form-field class="full-width" appearance="fill" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                    <mat-label>Title</mat-label>
                    <input matInput>
                </mat-form-field>
            </div>
        </div>
    </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nqxgkw

Comment: how do we put this 2 buttons inside mat card in the center ? https://imgur.com/a/3wC9pf5

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68216065/create-columns-in-angular-inside-material-card-layout?noredirect=1#comment120564793_68216065